# Jquery onClick has to start automatically after 5 seconds

Tags: jquery, onclick, explode

I have the following code, its makes the text explode onClick. But i need to have it explode after 5 second. Als it has to start automatically, without a click. Could someone tell me what i have to change?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fx(o) {
  var $o = $(o);

  $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
  $o.css("position", "relative");
  $("span", $o).each(function(i) {
    var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);
    var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);

    $(this).css({position: "relative",
      opacity: 1,
      fontSize: 50,
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    }).animate({
      opacity: 0,
      fontSize: 90,
      top: newTop,
      left:newLeft
    },1200);
  });
} </script>
```

```
<span onclick="fx(this)"><h1>Text Here</h1> </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `fx` function to this:

```
function fx(o) {
  setTimeout (
    function () {
      var $o = $(o);

      $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
      $o.css("position", "relative");
      $("span", $o).each(function(i) {
        var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);
        var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);

        $(this).css({position: "relative",
          opacity: 1,
          fontSize: 50,
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }).animate({
          opacity: 0,
          fontSize: 90,
          top: newTop,
          left:newLeft
        },1200);
      });
    },
    5000
  );
}
```

This delays the execution for 5 seconds (using the `setTimeout` function).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: Maybe i wasn't totally clear about it, but it has to start automatically after 5 seconds, do you know how i could do this ?

Comment: Already found the solution:

add to fx

    $(function() {
       setTimeout(function () {
         fx('#animateMe');
       }, 5000); 
    });

and give the span a id (animateMe)

Answer (score 2):

user setTimeout()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fx(o) {
      setTimeout(function(){var $o = $(o);

      $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
      $o.css("position", "relative");
      $("span", $o).each(function(i) {
        var newTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);
        var newLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);

        $(this).css({position: "relative",
          opacity: 1,
          fontSize: 50,
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }).animate({
          opacity: 0,
          fontSize: 90,
          top: newTop,
          left:newLeft
        },1200);
      });
    },5000);
    } </script>
```